# Debugging flask with Docker compose interpreter force debug mode off

Tags: python, flask, docker-compose, pycharm

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/03/docker-compose-getting-flask-up-and-running/) and after a long time I was able to debug the application. The problem is when I want the application to restart when I make changes locally. The problem is when I want the application to restart when I make changes locally. Creo que el problema es el docker-compose que agrega PyCharm

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f $HOME//PyCharmProjects/flask-compose/docker-compose.yml -f $HOME/PyCharmProjects/flask-compose/docker-compose.dev.yml -f $HOME/.PyCharm2019.1/system/tmp/docker-compose.override.263.yml up --exit-code-from web --abort-on-container-exit web
```

This file has the environmental variable `FLASK_DEBUG: "0"`, which overrides any environmental variable that I could set.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    command:
    - "python"
    - "-u"
    - "/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py"
    - "--module"
    - "--multiprocess"
    - "--qt-support=auto"
    - "--port"
    - "51422"
    - "--file"
    - "flask"
    - "run"
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: "/app:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_display:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/third_party/thriftpy:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev:/home/fferrin/.PyCharm2019.1/system/cythonExtensions"
      FLASK_DEBUG: "0"
      FLASK_APP: "flask-compose.py"
      PYTHONIOENCODING: "UTF-8"
      IPYTHONENABLE: "True"
      IDE_PROJECT_ROOTS: "/app"
      PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE: "1"
      PYDEVD_LOAD_VALUES_ASYNC: "True"
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: "1"
      FLASK_ENV: "development"
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this? This file is generated dynamically,

Thanks!

PD: I was not able to reach the endpoint unless I use the parameter

```
network_mode: "host"
```

in `docker-compose.dev.yml`. It may be the case that you have to update the repo or it's just a problem in my computer?

Comment: please don't paste screenshots of text.

Comment: what's generating that file ?  because if it's turning `FLASK_DEBUG` to `0`, you're right, it's going to come out as 0.  Is there a parameter for the generator for DEBUG too, just like network mode presumably?

Comment: I think PyCharm, because the number `263` in `$HOME/.PyCharm2019.1/system/tmp/docker-compose.override.263.yml` changes every time I run the container again, and I couldn't find where to set that option.